# Definition of "first excitation energy"?

Tags: energy, atomic-physics

I was solving a problem but I didn't know what the term "first excitation energy" means.

> The first excitation energy of the hydrogen atom is $10.2\text{eV}$. Calculate
>   the speed of the slowest electron that can excite a hydrogen atom.
>
> (Electron charge/mass ratio $e/m=1.7\times10^{11}\text{Ckg}^{-1}$.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy

Comment: @AV23: Sorry, edited

Comment: @AV23 Ionization energies are unrelated to this question.

Comment: @lemon the original version asked for ionization energy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrons occupy shells characterised by the [principal quantum number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_quantum_number), $n$. The lowest energy shell ($n=1$) is the ground-state. Above that you have the first excitation shell ($n=2$), the second excitation shell ($n=3$), and so on.

In the hydrogen atom, the energy states are given by the equation
$$ E_n=\frac{-13.6\,\mathrm{eV}}{n^2} $$
So the energy to transition from the ground-state to the first excitation state is

$$ E_2-E_1 = 10.2\,\mathrm{eV} $$

Answer (score 2):

If you have a ground state hydrogen atom, the the first excitation energy is the distance to the lowest unoccupied orbital i.e. it is the lowest energy that can excite an electronic transition.

The ground state is with the electron in the $1s$ orbital, and the next lowest energy orbital is the $2s$. So the first excitation energy corresponds to the transition $1s^1 \rightarrow 2s^1$. This is the first line in the [Lyman series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series#Lyman_series_.28n.E2.80.B2_.3D_1.29), with a wavelength of 121.57nm. If you calculate the corresponding energy you get 10.2eV.

Answer (score -1):

May be when number of proton and number of neutron  exceeds the magic number like 2,8,20,50,82,126 etc by one ,the binding energy of extra nucleon is less than the average value. Which is known as first excitation energy.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say here.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with nucleon numbers, your idea of first excitation energy is incorrect.